# what size puddle does a gallon of water produce?

Tags: fluid-statics

A accident purportedly occurred where a coffee urn spilled on a carpet, and then someone was electrocuted when standing in it . An observer seems to see the puddle is larger than should be expected . How could one prove it was larger using physics of fluids?

Comment: What do you mean with the puddle is larger, larger than what? Due to capillary action it is likely that the water will spread further into the carpet.

Comment: There is insufficient information for us to answer this question.

Comment: Edward - you need to be more specific

Comment: 1 gallon= ? Inches puddling before capillary action of soaking

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the puddle is on a flat smooth surface then the [depth of the puddle is given by](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension#Puddles_on_a_surface):

$$ h = \sqrt{ \frac{2\gamma(1 - \cos\theta)}{g\rho} } $$

where $\gamma$ is the surface tension of the coffee, $\theta$ is the contact angle, $\rho$ is the density and $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity. Once you have the puddle thickness, $h$, the puddle radius is related to the volume of coffee by:

$$ \pi r^2 h = V $$

But I'd be cautious about raising this in court as there are all sorts of other factors that will affect the puddle size and shape.

Comment: flat smooth _hydrophobic_ surface.

Comment: @jameslarge: in that case the contact angle will be approximately $\pi$ so $\cos\theta \approx -1$. You just need to Google for the surface tension and density of coffee (the density will be very close to the density of water).

Comment: It's on a carpet. All bets are off.